# Why doesn't the VSTO Word ContentControl have a Name property?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

When you [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb532208%28VS.90%29.aspx) a VSTO (not Word native) [content control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.contentcontrol%28VS.90%29.aspx), you specify the name:

```
controls.AddContentControl(wordRange, "foo", wdType);
```

Where controls is the VSTO (extended) Document.Controls collection.

You can later [look up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7wyeek%28VS.90%29.aspx) the control by name:

```
ContentControl myContentControl = controls["foo"];
```

So why in the world is there no Name property for ContentControl? (or ContentControlBase, or any of the other derivatives).

I'm implementing a wrapper class for the Document.Controls property that lets you add or iterate the content controls. When iterating the underlying Document.Controls, there's no way to look up the name of each control. (We need it to return an instance of our ContentControl wrapper).  So currently I'm doing this in our ContentControls wrapper class:

```
    public IEnumerator<IContentControl> GetEnumerator()
    {
        System.Collections.IEnumerator en = this.wordControls.GetEnumerator();
        while (en.MoveNext())
        {
            // VSTO Document.Controls includes all managed controls, not just 
            // VSTO ContentControls; return only those.
            if (en.Current is Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.ContentControl)
            {
                // The control's name isn't stored with the control, only when it was added,
                // so use a placeholder name for the wrapper.
                yield return new ContentControl("Unknown", (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.ContentControl)en.Current);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd prefer to not have to resort to keeping a map of names-to-wrapper-objects in our ContentControls object.  Can anyone tell me how to get the control's name (the name parameter that was passed to Controls.Add()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "name" argument is purely for ease of manipulation when you are programmatically adding a CC and then needing immediate access to it during the same instance of Word. After-the-fact access to a CC is by way of a GUID in the `ContentControl.ID` property. So in that sense, "name" is fairly useless for later access and manipulation as it is not retained in the WordprocessingML markup.

An easier way of approaching it is to just ignore the "name" designation all together, add a CC, grab it's `.ID` and then use that. Granted, the Guid is fairly meaningless to a human reader, but your program should be able to account for it.

If you really do need to grab a CC by a meaningful name, such as "foo", just use the `.Tag` property for your CC's name (it just needs to be unique for each CC though for your tags to work as names) and query the the ContentControlCollection by tags.

Comment: Thanks, figured something like that. It's just odd that they require a name in the Add() method but don't retain it; the name parameter should be optional, and it would be nice if their docs explained their reasoning. Not a big deal--we'll use the ID instead. Thanks!

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol: This article just came out today on this very subject - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg605189.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link! Some very useful info for what we are trying to accomplish.